# Is anything done with the "Send Feedback" (anonymous user feedback) data?

Tags: support, data-explorer, post-feedback

What's done with the anonymous user feedback data?

I get 10k-ers can view it; the data is now available for viewing in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60668/feedback-on-my-posts)

But does this data serve any purpose for improving the site?

There was a [discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99370/what-should-we-do-with-anonymous-user-feedback?rq=1) about what to do with the data, but as far as I can see, nothing has been done.

What purpose does it serve, apart from being recorded─what's it used for?

---

I see that in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320779/are-votes-by-anonymous-users-recorded), a user states that the message is deceptive and nothing happens to or with it.  Unfortunately, they're suspended, so I don't really think this is a reliable source.  Also, [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320779/are-votes-by-anonymous-users-recorded#comment1051318_320779) confirms the data was used in the 2015 Winter Bash.

What about any other time, or, more importantly, now?

Comment: It’s included in the 10k tools, and has been for months, if not longer. I haven’t found it particularly useful though

Comment: @Laurel Thanks;edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are votes by anonymous users recorded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320779/are-votes-by-anonymous-users-recorded) - Originally used for: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27618/getting-feedback-from-anonymous-users#comment250003_27618 (found by clicking on the tag).